# Heroku and Rails 3 beta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How to deploy rails 3 beta project on heroku?
When I try to do it I get this error:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Gemfile detected, running gem bundle
 !     Heroku push rejected, "gem bundle" failed, please check your Gemfile for errors.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 3 is now available on heroku

http://docs.heroku.com/rails3

cheers

Answer (score 1):

I would contact their technical support team. It looks like their deploy scripts are still using an old version of the bundler. It is up to 0.9.3 right now, and higher in the prerelease versions.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is currently running Ruby MRI version 1.8.6, rails 3 requires 1.8.7 or higher... as heroku is aimed at more production apps I doubt you see a bump until Rails 3 is officially released or even after.

http://docs.heroku.com/technologies